# How to write a function that print an array no matter what type it is?

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to know how to write a function that print an array no matter what type it is. Like if I give an array of integer numbers or string or whatever it just prints it.

I'm new to C++ so if it's possible can you not use templates and STL?

Comment: have you tried anything yet, if so post the code.

Comment: i did try some staff. none of them worked so why share the code .... i was trying to use void* which i couldn't get it to work...

Comment: That's the whole point! you should share your code(with `void*`), so we can tell you what was wrong, and eventually you can learn something from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the array/container `X` you can write something along these lines:

```
template <class X>
void print_all(X &x)
{
    for (auto y : x)
        std::cout << y << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Probably don't want to create copies in the loop.

Comment: Indeed - `for (auto &y : x)` would be better - otherwise a good answer though.

Comment: This is about the simplest case of templates you can get. We take in an object, not caring what type it is so long as we can iterate over it and output what is iterated over.

Comment: @PaulR: Better make that `auto &&` or `auto const &` in case `X` is `const`.